# Multi dimension sorting [Python]

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is the structure :

```
            #  0. [File1]
            #  1. [File2]
            #  2. [X] entre f1 et f2
            #  3. [identites] |
            #  4. [position] (position in f1, position inf2)
            #  5. [hashcode] 
    results_struct = ([nb_comon_ngs, idents_sum, gaps_sum, alength_sum, word_position, ns_sum])
```

Suppose I want to sort that structure on the "Position in f1" : cell[4][0].

Sample :

```
results_struct = [
[14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
[32,  4, 16, 13, 13, 32, 22, 18, 22, 31, 24, 23, 40, 35],
[19,  0,  2,  2,  1, 19,  0,  0,  2, 19,  2,  1,  1,  3],
[51,  4, 18, 15, 14, 51, 22, 18, 24, 50, 26, 24, 41, 38],
[(48, 112), (60, 51), (45, 49), (46, 50), (59, 134), (49, 113), (34, 27), (35, 28), (43, 47), (50, 114), (53, 121), (57, 132), (32, 25), (41, 45)],
['ilya', 'pluspas', 'pasbeaucoup', 'beaucoupplus', 'estplus', 'yaune', 'pourdépaserde', 'dépaserdela', 'oupluspas', 'enadeux', 'queontailleurs', 'laestplus', 'suffisammentpourdépaserde', '100oupluspas']
```

]

```
#becomes
[
    [14, ...],
    [40, ...], 
    [1, ...], 
    [41, ...], 
    [(32, 25), (34, 27), (35, 28), (41, 45), (43, 47), (45, 49), (46, 50), (48, 112), (49, 113), (50, 114), (53, 121), (57, 132),(59, 134), (60, 51)], 
    ['suffisammentpourdépaserde', ...]
]
```

Why is this :

```
r = sorted(results_struct, key=lambda o: o[4][0])
```

not working ?

It raises "*TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable*"

I've tried many key/cmp/sorted/sort variation with no success.
How should I proceed ?

Comment: First off, don't sort with both key and cmp.

Comment: Edit - only key.: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Give a sample of the input. The description you have is extremely unclear. Give me some code I can run to initialize a sample input.

Comment: Also, explain exactly how it is not working. This question is very hard to understand.

Comment: I made it way easier. A sample is on its way.

Comment: What are `f1` and `f2`? Are they integers? Anyway, indexing like `results_struct[f1][f2]` is weird because `results_struct` is a 1-D list.

Comment: That was a mispelling. But `results_struct` is five-dimensions, isn't it ?
BTW thanks, it's getting clearer

Comment: Anyway, the entries are `set`s (or, at least, this is how you made them look), so they can't be indexed at all.

Comment: None of the sample you gave constitutes valid Python code. Please provide something that I can run that says `result_set = ...` so I can test your code and suggest an improvement.

Comment: You need to explain away `f1`, `f2` and tell us what is in that `list` (I guess), because, as @ForceBru says, it looks like `set`s. And no, what you have shown here is not a multidimensional anything, certainly not 5D.

Comment: Now ? Printed out of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the lengths of the inner lists are equal:

```
r = sorted(list(zip(*results_struct)), key=lambda o: o[4][0])
```

Here `list(zip(*results_struct))` looks like this:

```
[
    (14, 32, 19, 51, (32, 25), 'ilya'),
    # and so on
]
```

Then, `o` represents one row, `o[4]` is its fourth element, which appears to be a tuple, which is perfectly subscriptable.

---

If you're using Python 2.x, you could omit `list` safely.

Comment: HOw do I get the old structure back after the "list" use ? Is `list(zip(*r))` reversible ?
(I'm using python 3.6)

Comment: You run it through `zip` again the way it's done in my answer